# Getting the page that loaded my image

Tags: php, javascript, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I want to show some dynamic info on my image, but it needs to grab the HTML of the page that loaded my image.

There might me some security risks by that, but there should be another way since I've seen an image that does that on some forum.

The image that I'm rendering will be used on a site that I do not own, but can only add to the page, like make a post which will contain the image. The example I was pointing at was [this](http://www.powerbot.org/community/user/517006-shadow/) where it shows 'Welcome to my profile, (user)'

Here's how it looks like on my pc,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on client configuration it should be available in the `Referer` HTTP header

In PHP you can get at this with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`

Comment: I don't need the URL though. I need to get a specific element in the HTML that contains the person's display name.

Comment: i think there is information missing from the question that makes it impossible to answer

Comment: Added some more info with the example.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm it was much simpler than I thought. It looks like all he did was just simply connect to the referrer url, read the input stream, then go to that url again, read previous users, grab the latest one and just write that name onto the image.